# How to hide robot framework code base and share only binary file to client?

Tags: python, robotframework, executable, robotium

I automated the Test Suite using Robot Framework-Selenium base on PYTHON 27. This same Test Suite needs to execute on client side.

But Company do not want to share code base with client.

Is there anyway that  I can create binary file of Robot Framework and share the same binary file with client instead of sharing a actually code ?
like in Java we create .jar file.

Kindly help me I am looking for solution from last three days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything you can do. Robot doesn't have the ability to parse binary files, so any solution would have to include converting your binary files to text files on the client machine.

Comment: I want to convert the robot code into binary executable file. And execute this binary executable file on clients end.  So that client will not able to see my code. and execution will done clients end